# Aplicar zoom à miniatura de imagem selecionada no Input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou usando o plugin elevate zoom para dar zoom em miniaturas e estou gerando as miniaturas em um campo input file para exibir as imagens que o cliente escolheu para fazer upload.

Gostaria de aproveitar o código abaixo para aplicar à miniatura gerada, o plugin elevate zoom. Mas da forma que tentei não dá certo.

Podem me ajudar?

```
var arquivos = new Array();

$(function(){
    $('#fotos').on('change',function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var totalFiles = $(this).get(0).files.length;

        if(totalFiles == 0) {
          $('#message').text('Selecionar Fotos' );
        }
        if ( totalFiles > 1) {
            $('#message').text( totalFiles+' arquivos selecionados' );
        } else {
            $('#message').text( totalFiles+' arquivo selecionado' );
        }

        var htm='<ol>';

        for (var i=0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
             var c = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'item_white' : 'item_grey';
             var arquivo = $(this).get(0).files[i];
             var fileV = new readFileView(arquivo, i);

             arquivos.push(arquivo);                         

             htm += '<li class="'+c+'">';
             htm += '  <div class="box-images">';
             htm += '     <img  ';
             htm += '        class="item elevate-image" ';
             htm += '        data-img="'+i+'" ';
             htm += '        data-id="'+id+'" ';
             htm += '        border="0"'; 
             htm += '        data-zoom-image="'+arquivo.name+'">';
             htm += '  </div>';
             htm += '  <span>'+arquivo.name+'</span>';
             htm += '   <a href="javascript:removeFile('+i+',\''+id+'\')" class="remove">x</a>';
             htm += '</li>'+"\n";

         }


        htm += '</ol>';
           $('#lista').html(htm);
           $('#arquivos').val(arrayParaString(arquivos));
           $('.elevate-image').elevateZoom();
    });

});
```

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title><?php echo $constantes->getTituloSiteAdmin(); ?></title>
     <?php  require_once("../_global/_meta/meta.ini"); ?>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../_img/favicon.ico" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/admin.css" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/upload.css" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/menu.css" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_global/_css/jHtmlArea.css" />

     <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_funcoes/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_funcoes/_js/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_funcoes/_js/readImage.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_funcoes/_js/upload.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
       <div id="topo"><h1><?php echo $constantes->getCabecalhoAdmin(); ?></h1></div>
       <div id="menu">
          <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once($menu.".php"); ?></div>
       </div>
       <div id="cont">
          <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once("imoveisCadastrarConteudo.php"); ?></div>
       </div>
       <div id="base">
          <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once($base.".php"); ?></div>
       </div>
       <div id="final">
          <div class="sessoes"><?php require_once("final.php"); ?></div>
       </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

O erro que dá no console é esse,

```
http://localhost/php/dinamicaimoveis.com.br/admin/undefined Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

e não dá zoom.

Mas as miniaturas são mostradas

Se eu colocar uma imagem no `body`, ela dá zoom. Mas essas imagens que são geradas pelo JavaScript para mostrar as miniaturas do input file, estas não aceitam o plugin

Agora esta faltando apenas conseguir pegar o src da imagem

Comment: Ja tentou instanciar o plugin depois de colocar estas imagens no html?

Comment: Como assim/? Eu coloquei o html no corpo da pergunta agora

Comment: Mas a miniatura é essa mesmo?  $('[data-img="'+i+'"]')

Comment: Cara, você pode usar o console na parte de sources e debugar por lá, assim você vai saber o que está chegando em cada linha e validar se a variável i está com o valor que realmente precisa estar.

Comment: Olá. Consegue fazer um exemplo no jsfiddle? Fica muito mais facil ajudar.

Comment: Sim: https://jsfiddle.net/tujemnsL/ . Detalhe, atualizei a pergunta!

Comment: Obrigado. Quando ia responder voce já tinha a resposta certa (veja o comentario do @patetico)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu erro está neste comando:

```
$('[data-img="'+i+'"]').addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

O jQuery retorna objetos jQuery e não possui o método addEventlistener, mas oferece outros atalhos pra fazer isso. Dentre eles, a melhor para o seu caso seria

```
$('[data-img="'+i+'"]').change(readImage);
```

Você pode conferir a documentação [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/change/) caso precise fazer alterações na sua callback.

Comment: Sim, mas parece que falta algo. Já atualizei na pergunta. Não dá erro. Mas o zoom também não funciona!

Comment: Você está chamando  o comando antes de inserir o elemento na página. Adicione esta linha no final do script (deve ser executada só uma vez mesmo) `$('body').on('change', '[data-img]', readImage)`

Comment: Acho que estou fazendo confusão aqui. Não preciso da função readImage(). Pois isso, já esta sendo feito que é exibir a miniatura. Mas o elevate zoom pede só a instanciação da classe e a chamada ao plugin. Como essas imagens estão sendo geradas após o carregamento do body isso deve estar atrapalhando o zoom da imagem pois não encontra o <img class="elevate-zomm"..> pedida pelo plugin

Comment: fiz para ver se facilita a compreensão do meu erro: https://jsfiddle.net/tujemnsL/

Comment: Seu problema era que você estava chamando o plugin antes de injetar o src da imagem. Além disso seu fiddle parece ter usado um plugin diferente, então eu tive que mudar `$().elevateZoom()` para `$().ezPlus()`. Confira minhas alterações na sua função `readFileView`: https://jsfiddle.net/patetico/tujemnsL/2/

Comment: Olha só. Funcionou. foi só trocar o endereço do Plugin Agora só mais uma ajuda: Quando faz o zoom, ele fica sempre abaixo da imagem e nos caso em que a imagem esta no fim da página, seu zoom perde parte da amostra. Será que existe uma forma de configurar o zoom para sair na área visível do browser?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação do plugin. Tanto o elevateZoom quanto o ezPlus possuem vários exemplos pra você usar como base pra escolher a melhor solução pro seu caso.